# Did the atomic bombing of Hiroshima and Nagasaki contribute to Japan's surrender?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, japan, nuclear-weapons

Even before the atomic bombing of Hiroshima and Nagasaki, the war situation had developed not necessarily to Japan's advantage. Allied forces had been taking island after island, and were firebombing dozens of cities to the ground. So I assume the atomic bombing of Hiroshima and Nagasaki wasn't the sole cause of Japan's surrender. But did it contribute to Japan's surrender?

A sizeable proportion of Americans apparently believe that the bombing contributed to Japan's surrender. Even some who disapprove of the atomic bombing think it contributed to Japan's surrender. From [Majority Supports Use of Atomic Bomb on Japan in WWII](http://www.gallup.com/poll/17677/majority-supports-use-atomic-bomb-japan-wwii.aspx), 57% approved of the bombing and 38% disapprove, and 80% think that the bombing saved American lives, so at least 18% (38 + 80 - 100) both disapprove of the bombing and think it saved American lives. (As a side note, at the time of the war, there was some public sentiment in favour of more bombing regardless of whether it was necessary: 22.7% of the population in December 1945 wished [more bombs had been dropped](http://www.indiana.edu/~futhist2/Part4/Wk12/reactions.htm) before it could surrender)

I've come across articles claiming that the atomic bombing didn't contribute to Japan's surrender, but they've usually been by people with some potential bias against the bombing. For example I've read (the now paywalled) [The Bomb Didn't Beat Japan - Stalin Did](http://foreignpolicy.com/2013/05/30/the-bomb-didnt-beat-japan-stalin-did/) (referring to the USSR's war against Japan) which, according to a [comment](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10218/how-many-lives-were-estimated-to-have-been-saved-by-the-hiroshima-and-nagasaki-b#comment25119_10261) in the question "How many lives were estimated to have been saved by the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs?", was by a lifetime opponent of nuclear weapons.

The question [How many lives were estimated to have been saved by the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombs?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/10218/421) is related, but it's assuming that the atomic bombing contributed to Japan's surrender, and is asking about the costs and benefits of doing it.

Comment: Plenty of people have argued that the bombings were not **necessary** for inducing Japan to surrender; others have argued that it was **less important** than the Soviet entry. I've yet to see anyone argue that the atomic bombs didn't **"contribute" at all**, however.

Comment: @Semaphore Australian Greens MP Jamie Parker [linked](https://twitter.com/GreensJamieP/status/231912112123961344) to an article by the neonazi, holocaust-denying "Institute of Historical Review", which ended with "General Curtis LeMay, who had pioneered precision bombing of Germany and Japan (and who later headed the Strategic Air Command and served as Air Force chief of staff), put it most succinctly: "The atomic bomb had nothing to do with the end of the war."" I don't know if they count though.

Comment: I wouldn't pay attention to anything coming out of the Institute of Historical Review. But Curtis LeMay did say that, but it wasn't a reasoned argument as much as him being bitter at the atomic bombs stealing credit from his bombers. He went to explain that *"The war would have been over in two weeks without the Russians entering and without the atomic bomb."* - so he thinks the atomic bombing contributed to Japan's surrender by hastening it by *up to* two weeks. I don't think he ever gave an exact breakdown of Soviet/Atomic contribution though. It really wasn't a well reasoned claim.

Comment: @Semaphore It could be if the surrender was already decided upon. So, the question is correct.

Comment: @Semaphore, the article linked by the OP [The Bomb Didn't Beat Japan...Stalin Did](http://foreignpolicy.com/2013/05/30/the-bomb-didnt-beat-japan-stalin-did/) claims exactly that.

Comment: @PaulDraper No, it argues the Soviet entry was more important - as I said. It doesn't attempt to prove atomic bombings had no effect at all.

Comment: Might have an answer [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/34646/what-were-the-reasons-for-japans-surrender-in-wwii). Can't really say if this is a duplicate, but very similar question anyway.

Answer (score 16):

It did and the Japanese emperor, in announcing the surrender of Japan to Allied forces specifically referred to atomic weapons in his speech which was broadcast to the entire country with these words:

> ... Moreover, the enemy has begun to employ a new and most cruel bomb,
>   the power of which to do damage is, indeed, incalculable, taking the
>   toll of many innocent lives. Should We continue to fight, not only
>   would it result in an ultimate collapse and obliteration of the
>   Japanese nation, but also it would lead to the total extinction of
>   human civilization. ....

[Imperial Rescript on the Termination of the War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyokuon-h%C5%8Ds%C5%8D) issued by the [Chrysanthemum Throne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrysanthemum_Throne) on August 14, 1945.

Comment: While I too agree it was due to the A-bomb, the [article](http://foreignpolicy.com/2013/05/30/the-bomb-didnt-beat-japan-stalin-did/) mentioned by the OP says "The Bomb was the perfect excuse for having lost the war [and] served to deflect blame from Japan’s leaders.", but it was not the real reason.

Comment: wtf? the japanese thought that all human life would be eradicated together with all human life in Japan if further nuking of Japan had occurred? the bombs were nowhere close to `wiping out all of humanity from being dropped over japan` ..

Answer (score 4):

The atomic bombings likely sped up the surrender of the Japanese forces, but it wasn't the only cause. It was a larger one, but not the only one. The Soviet invasion of Manchuria also helped speed up the surrender, as Japan was struggling. Without the bombings, America likely would've had to invade Japan, possibly with help from the Soviets. The question itself, is YES, in all caps, since it is pretty straight forward.